# Verifying cpu-contention on a single core using real time reported in GC?

Tags: java, linux, performance, garbage-collection

I have a device with `ARMv7 Cortex-A8  (1 Core , 13-pipeline depth)` and 512M 
running over 250 threads; However, top commands load average seems to be either below 1 or slightly over 1.5 [1].

On using vmstat[2] , I can see that procs(r) seems to be frequently very high compared to the cores available on the device [2], in this case it is just a single core cpu.

On profiling GC collection on one of the Process running on the device, I get the following[3]:, It is interesting to note that real-time is significantly higher compared to (user+sys) time;   So, for example, GC is reported to take 226 millisec, out of that real-time took 230 millisec.

Given the following:
Is it correct to assume, the device is suffering from cpu-contention
If, so would CPU-contention be reflected in the average load on using top?
Is average load on top a good indicator on cpu contention caused by threads?
What else can cause high values for vmstat's procs -r count?

```
[3]
2019-01-21T10:18:55.607+0000: 78.012: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-01-21T10:18:55.608+0000: 78.013: [DefNew: 5632K->576K(5632K), 0.2220500 secs] 13789K->9541K(17928K), 0.2260043 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.23 secs]

2019-01-21T10:26:18.394+0000: 520.799: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-01-21T10:26:18.396+0000: 520.801: [DefNew: 9423K->601K(9792K), 0.1988650 secs] 30450K->21806K(31360K), 0.2060742 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.21 secs]

2019-01-21T10:19:51.661+0000: 134.066: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-01-21T10:19:51.663+0000: 134.068: [DefNew: 9560K->766K(9792K), 0.3196409 secs] 22499K->13926K(31360K), 0.3309429 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.33 secs] 


[1]
//Top
top - 10:40:04 up  1:58,  8 users,  load average: 1.66, 1.23, 1.64
Threads: 251 total,   3 running, 248 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie

[2]
Vmsatat 
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 5  0      0  16136  22012 232432    0    0     0     0 1614 3670 40 35 26  0  0
 3  0      0  21740  22012 232444    0    0     0     0 2576 5744 61 39  0  0  0
 0  0      0  21628  22012 232448    0    0     0     0 2006 4809 52 22 26  0  0
 0  0      0  21740  22012 232448    0    0     0     0  595  843  5  8 87  0  0
 3  0      0  21740  22012 232448    0    0     0     0  140  309  2  4 94  0  0
 0  0      0  21740  22036 232448    0    0     0   116  220  349  8  3 89  0  0
 2  0      0  21740  22036 232448    0    0     0     0  125  282  2  3 95  0  0
 0  0      0  21740  22036 232448    0    0     0     0  129  280  2  4 94  0  0
 1  0      0  21740  22036 232448    0    0     0     0  127  266  3  3 94  0  0
 0  0      0  21740  22036 232448    0    0     0     4  145  315  3  3 94  0  0
 2  0      0  18988  22036 232448    0    0     0     0 1619 3888 43 38 19  0  0
 2  0      0  24592  22040 232444    0    0     0    36 2315 5472 64 36  0  0  0
 0  0      0  24480  22040 232444    0    0     0     0 1766 4273 51 23 26  0  0
 0  0      0  24512  22040 232444    0    0     0     0  658 1033  6  7 87  0  0
 0  0      0  24544  22040 232444    0    0     0     0  163  353  1  4 95  0  0
 0  0      0  24544  22040 232444    0    0     0     0  122  242  3  3 94  0  0
 1  0      0  24544  22040 232444    0    0     0     0  142  304  1  4 95  0  0
 0  0      0  24544  22040 232444    0    0     0     0  137  294  2  4 94  0  0
 0  0      0  24544  22040 232444    0    0     0     0  137  276  3  4 93  0  0
 0  0      0  24544  22040 232444    0    0     0     0  134  308  3  2 95  0  0
 9  0      0  19080  22040 232448    0    0     0     0 1952 4268 42 37 20  0  0
 1  0      0  24460  22040 232456    0    0     0     0 2058 4523 65 35  0  0  0
 2  0      0  24560  22040 232452    0    0     0     0 3057 7385 58 42  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The Linux load average represents (roughly speaking) the number of processes or threads on the operating system's process queues in `R`, `D` or (historically) `W` states.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9465/understanding-top-and-load-average

---

> Is average load on `top` a good indicator on CPU contention caused by threads?

Not necessarily.

1. It could be caused by processes rather than threads.
2. The `D` state means that the process is waiting on "uninteruptible" I/O: typically a file system operation.   So if you are accessing a slow file system (e.g. a network file server that is heavily loaded), that is liable to push up the load average.

> What else can cause high values for `vmstat`'s `procs -r` count?

According to the `vmstat` manual entry, the `r` column is effectively the number of processes (or threads) in `R` state.   The `d` column is the number of processes in `D` state.  Note that these are instantaneous measures, not averages.

So, the answer is processes.

---

The other thing to note is that the JVM may suspend all of the application threads (for the process) while running the GC.  Depending on the GC implementation, this suspension may be for the duration of the GC run, or for certain phases only.

So your observation that the GC CPU time and clock time are almost the same does not mean that there is no CPU contention.

Conversely, a major discrepancy between the GC CPU time and clock time doesn't necessarily mean that there is CPU contention (with either application threads or other processes).  Another possibility is contention for (real) memory pages; i.e. virtual memory thrashing.

Comment: thanks very much for answering,  there are few things that are still not clear ; for example, in the GC.log , there are several instances of  GC thread consuming only 20% of the total GC time;  In the log extract below, GC took around 330ms, and GC thread took 60ms, however, there is something happening in the kernel that accounts for 80% of the delay. 

2019-01-21T10:19:51.661+0000: 134.066: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-01-21T10:19:51.663+0000: 134.068: [DefNew: 9560K->766K(9792K), 0.3196409 secs] 22499K->13926K(31360K), 0.3309429 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.33 secs]